# How to display only search result from firebase in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, search, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I want to display only search result from firebase using angular version 8. I have data of customers stored in firebase and I want to search specific result by name.

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { CustomerService } from '../shared/customer.service';
    import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-customer-list',
      templateUrl: './customer-list.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./customer-list.component.css']
    })
    export class CustomerListComponent implements OnInit { 

      customerArray = [];
      searchText: string = "";
      findName: string;

      constructor(private customerService: CustomerService) { }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.customerService.getCustomers().subscribe(
          list => {
            this.customerArray = list.map(item => {
              return {
                $key: item.key,
                ...item.payload.val()
              };
            });
          });
      }

      filterCondition(customer) {
        return 
     customer.fullName.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.searchText.toLowerCase()) != -1;
      }
  find(findName){
     // query to check the enter name exist is firebase and display it
   }
}
```

I expect only search data to be display but complete list of customers is displaying

Comment: `angularfire2` is an old version library. You need to install `@angular/fire` library.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't ever actually using the `filterCondition` you have written, so of course all the customers are going to be displayed.

Its hard to tell if there aren't other problems, as you haven't specified an expected output or sample data in your question, but you at least need to change the callback you use when you subscribe to something more like this:

```js
this.customerService.getCustomers().subscribe(
  list => {
    this.customerArray = list.filter(this.filterCondition).map(item => {
      // contents omitted for berevity
    });
  });
```